# Java Interpret 64 bit Integer as a float

Tags: java, double

I have a 64 bit integer that I would like to interpret as a float.

I don't mean I want to re-assign something like 4 to 4.0.

I have the follow 8 bytes of data:

Dec (int):   4619191942746344941

Dec (float): 6.6666000000000000

Hex:         401AAA9930BE0DED

I have 4619191942746344941 stored in a variable in my java code.  How do I convert this to 6.6666000000000000?

Comment: The first step when approaching things like this is *read the documentation*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So which documentation should he have read?  Those of us who already know the answer know which javadoc to look at.  Those who don't--an answer like this can be like saying "Here's a haystack called the Java API Specification, go look there for your needle".

Comment: @ajb: I'd've started with `Double`, and then if necessary continued with `Long` (but of course, it wouldn't have been necessary).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure, and I would have too.  But you and I already know enough about the language so that we'd have an idea where to start.  I'm not sure a less experienced programmer would know that.  (It's not like he's using the `Double` class; if someone needs to know how to use a particular class they're using, it's pretty straightforward to tell them to look at the javadoc for that class.  But that doesn't apply here.)

Answer (score 6):

Use [Double.longBitsToDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)):

```
class Test { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Double.longBitsToDouble(0x401AAA9930BE0DEDl));
  }
}
```

prints

```
6.6666
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the bit representation of a `double` that happens to be in a `long` to a `double` with the `Double.longBitsToDouble` method.

```
long test = 0x401aaa9930be0dedL;
double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(test);
System.out.println(d);
```

Output:

```
6.6666
```

You can always cast the resultant `double` to a `float` if that's what you really need.